# How to convert HTML page into PDF in PHP?

Tags: php

I have generated an E-bill using html, css, bootstrap and php. Is there any way I can get it directly into PDF format (easily downloadable format)?

What all I could find was creating pdf using the code(FPDF etc). But that's not what I want. I already have the e-slip structure ready.

Thanks

Comment: What you try is unconventional for ecommerce, the specific creation of a PDF by means of a library, (fpdf, tcpsf or libpdf) is the way to go. If you want to convert a html page into pdf format you need either a headless browser or you can use the imagick suite. You will have to invest a lot of time to get images and spacings right that way, however.

Comment: If you do not wish to use a conversion library directly, you could consider using something like the LEADTOOLS Cloud Conversion service which provide Web API methods the support the conversion of multiple formats while retaining text. These APIs are available for use with PHP (https://services.leadtools.com/documentation/tutorials/php-conversion-tutorial). Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of these Cloud Services.